# When do you omit 'it' in phrases such as 'would appreciate it if you shared'?

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction

What's the difference between

> If you have any ideas about how to improve one's efficiency in studying
> math, then I would appreciate it if you shared them

and

> If you have any ideas about how to improve one's efficiency in
> studying math, then I would appreciate if you shared them

?

Comment: ***to appreciate*** is normally a ***transitive*** verb (i.e. - it takes an "object", being the thing which is appreciated). In your context the pronoun subject *should* be present, but because it would normally be completely "unstressed", it wouldn't be that noticeable if you didn't articulate it at all. But it's not actually "correct", and given your relatively formal use of pronoun ***one***, I'd say it ***is*** noticeably "off" as a ***written text***. As a general principle, don't omit the article in such contexts.

Comment: Mixing you and one seems strange.